# Sub-slicing elements in a list

Tags: python, list, slice

I'm trying to slice elements in a list, taking two characters off from the lest of each one. Desired output is this:

> ["e","o","ree","ur"]

```
lst = ["one","two","three","four"]

lst2 = []
for x in lst:
    lst2.append((lst[:2]))

print(lst2)
# this is not what I want but is resulting from this code:                              
['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two']]
```

Comment: `lst2.append((x[:2]))`

Comment: _"I'm trying to slice elements in a list"_. `lst[:2]` slices the _list_. `x` is the element in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = ["one","two","three","four"]

lst2 = [x[2:] for x in lst]
print(lst2) # ['e', 'o', 'ree', 'ur']
```